# AngularFire doesn't trigger change detection

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire and Angular 8 to build an app but I have a silly problem (I believe it is silly actually).

I built a simple service to wrap `AngularFireAuth`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { User } from 'firebase';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private user: Subject<User> = new Subject();
  private isLoggedIn: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.user.next(user);
      this.isLoggedIn.next(user !== null);
    });
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Then, I injected it in my `HomeComponent` and subscribed to the `Observable` returned by the `isAuthenticated` method:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html'
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe((isAuth) => {
      this.isAuthenticated = isAuth;
      console.log(`User is authenticated? ${this.isAuthenticated}`);
    });
  }
}
```

However, when the arrow function passed to the `subscribe` method is invoked, no re-rendering is executed. But, the `console.log` call *does* show "User is authenticated? true" on DevTools.

Some other tests that I've done: if I call `setTimeout` from within the arrow function passed to `subscribe`, the result is the same. No re-render and the message on DevTools says "User is authenticated? true".

But, if I invoke `setTimeout` (in this test with a 10 secs delay) outside `subscribe`, the component is re-rendered after these 10 seconds:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html'
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe((isAuth) => {
      this.isAuthenticated = isAuth;
      console.log(`User is authenticated? ${this.isAuthenticated}`);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      console.log(`User is authenticated? ${this.isAuthenticated}`);
    }, 10000)
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? What have I misunderstood?

Comment: this.isLoggedIn.next(user !== null); What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: i can't answer this phenomenon but you could force the update with `ChangeDetectorRef .detectChanges()`  https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges

Comment: Hi, @varundhariyal. I'm sending the `next` value to the subscribers, in this case `true` or `false`. This, apparently, is not the problem as the `true` value gets there.

Answer (score 0):

it's because after component init you're calling your authentication
call it in constructor it works

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html'
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

   constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
     this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe((isAuth) => {
      this.isAuthenticated = isAuth;
      console.log(`User is authenticated? ${this.isAuthenticated}`);
    });
    }

  ngOnInit(){}

}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not the problem. The behaviour doesn't change when I put on the constructor. That is, the bug is still there. Thanks though.